# What is the purpose of castling in chess?

Tags: chess

Having played chess on occasion I know the basic rules and moves to the game. However, it seems like a possibly wasted move when there are players who play a dominant game of chess and don't castle their king. Is castling a necessary move or is it more of a preference choice by the player? [image]

Answer (score 7):

Castling is always an option - it is never forced upon a player. It is however a very commonly taken option as it:

- places the king in an easily defended position
- moves the rook towards the centre of the board where it is easily developed
- and does all that in one move, improving the player's tempo